# Multiple files attached and sending an email by using Golang

Tags: go, email

I am using email Golang to send email and I am unable to send HTML content and attach more than one file and content. How to add more attached files and more than one table shown in the body email? I got the result by database.

```
m.Attach(cf.Attach) //attachment
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the .`xlxs` file over the disk then attach it using `path`. It will work perfectly.

Here is a sample code and it's working fine :

```
func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "a@gmail.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "b@gmail.com")
    m.SetAddressHeader("Cc", "c@gmail.com", "Vande")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello! New Mail")
    m.SetBody("text/html", "Hello <b>Bob</b> and <i>Cora</i>!")
    m.Attach("attach.xlsx")

    d := gomail.NewDialer("smtp.gmail.com", 2525, "user", "password")
    d.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
        panic(err)

    } else {
        fmt.Print("sent")
    }

}
```

Project Architecture :

```
send_mail    //project name
  attach.xlxs  //file
  main.go
  go.mod
```

Comment: Thank you a lot,the code is fine but i wanna more attached file because i have two files excel... so and i wanna add the data as HTML code as i wrote the above. thanks for your efforts.